# How to change the state of another component in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-state

I'm trying to make popup windows component.

**There is the start of popup component:**

The component gets 2 props `activity` is true/false, and `content` is view component inside popup window.

I have the state called `window` and it needs for changing visibility in styles. I have a close button that hide popup window. I don't know how, but I need that this close button send the false value to another component.

```
const Modal = ({ activity, content }) => {
  const [window, setWindow] = useState(activity);

  return (
    <ModalWrapper isActive={window}>
      <Section>
        <Content>
          <Close onClick={() => setWindow(false)}>Close Window</Close>
          {content}
        </Content>
      </Section>
    </ModalWrapper>
  )
}
```

Another component that open the popup.

If button was clicked the active state is changing and send the activity prop with true value. After this I can close popup by clicking the close button. But after this the "other component" still will be true and after this I can't click the popup again.

```
const [active, setActive] = useState(null);

const handleClick = () => {
  setActive(<Modal activity={true} content={<Feedback />} />);
}

return (
  <>
    {active}
    <NavbarWrapper>
      <OrderButton onClick={handleClick}>Замовити сайт</OrderButton>
    </NavbarWrapper>
  </>
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I typically like to use a parent component with a state that controls what is being shown. You can learn more about [State React Hooks here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html).

If you use conditional rendering, and the condition is based on state, you'll get great results.

To hide the modal, you just need to pass a function along that can be called by the child to hide itself.

I like to use objects as the state object. It keeps it simple and clean, and you can change multiple state variables in a single setState() call, whereas if you use multiple useState hooks then it gets funky when you have to set two of them at once.

```
function Parent({ ...props }){

    const [state, setState] = React.useState({
        showModal: false
    })

    return (
        <section className="parent">
            {
                state.showModal
                    ? <Modal
                        props={... }
                        closeModal={() => {
                            setState({
                                ...state, // Use deconstructing to preserve other values in the state object
                                showModal: false // Now set the variable to false
                            })
                        }}
                    />
                    : <></>
            }
            <button onClick={() => {
                setState({
                    ...state, // Use deconstructing to preserve other values in the state object
                    showModal: true // Now set the variable to false
                })
            }} type="button">
                Show Modal
            </button>
        </section>
    )

}

function Modal({ closeModal, ...props }){

    return (
        <div className="modal">
            <button onClick={closeModal}></button>
        </div>
    )

}
```