# Change the state of another component using functionnal components in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a button in my header that has to switch the state of the lateral menu of the page (to know if it has to be shown or not). I found out on Internet how to do so using Class Components, but not with Functional Components, do you have any idea on how to achieve that ?

Here's a simplification of my actual code in order to reproduce my issue (I removed all useless code).

App.js :

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
        <Header />
        <div>
            <LateralMenu />
        </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The Header component :

```js
function Header() {
    const [lateralIsOpen, setLateralIsOpen] = useState(true);

    function changeLateralMenu() {
        setLateralIsOpen(!lateralIsOpen);
    }

    return (
        <header>
            <div onClick={ changeLateralMenu }>
        </header>
    );
}
```

And the LateralMenu component :

```js
function Header() {
    const [lateralIsOpen, setLateralIsOpen] = useState(true);

    return (
        <section>
            { lateralIsOpen ? "open" : "closed" }
        </section>
    );
}
```

I tried (but maybe not correctly) to declare the `lateralIsOpen` State in the App component and sending it through props to my children componenents (`Header` & `LateralMenu`).

I also tried looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74156556/how-to-change-the-state-of-another-component-in-react) (and a few others) which is pretty similar, but don't see how I can apply it in my case because (as I understand) he uses a button in the parent component, that changes a state in the parent component, and then send it to the children through props... Where in my case, the button to switch it is already in a child.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you to move the state out of the `LateralMenu` to the parent (`App`) and then just pass the *toggle* function to the `Header` to toggle it.

```
export default function App() {
  const [lateralIsOpen, setLateralIsOpen] = useState(true);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header toggleLateral={() => setLateralIsOpen((prev) => !prev)} />
      <div>
        <LateralMenu isOpen={lateralIsOpen} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

function Header({ toggleLateral }) {
  function changeLateralMenu() {
    toggleLateral();
  }

  return (
    <header>
      <div onClick={changeLateralMenu}>click</div>
    </header>
  );
}

function LateralMenu({ isOpen }) {
  return <section>lateral is {isOpen ? 'open' : 'closed'}</section>;
}
```

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-heyrovsky-z75njd